# Best way to cast java.lang.object to customized object on using HQL select statement on multiple fields on an Entity Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

In this scenario rather than doing complete **select on object**,have decided to go for **select statement on fields required only**.Hence the queries generated will be less.

Once the result is in,i want to cast back to original values and return them to calling method.

**Please suggest any alternative efficient approach.**

```
      public class Student {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            private Integer id;

            @Column(name="enroll_id")
            private String enrollmentId;

            public Student(Integer id, String enrollmentId) {
             super();
             this.id = id;
             this.enrollmentId = enrollmentId;
             }
               // source code continues
            }

     public List<Student> getStudentList(){

        Query multipleSelect=em.createQuery("select student.id,student.enrollmentId from Student as student");

        List<Object[]> studentList=multipleSelect.getResultList();

        List<Student> studentArrayList=new ArrayList<Student>();

        for(Object[] list:studentList){
            Integer id=((Integer)list[0]);
            String eId=((String)list[1]);
            studentArrayList.add(new Student(id, eId));
        }

        return studentArrayList;
    }
```

Comment: The best way would be what you're doing, but using a class different from Student, that would only contain the fields retrieved from the database, and would not be an entity. If I call a method returning a List<Student>, I'd expect them to have all the fields a student is supposed to have, and to be managed by the current persistence context. Not to be detached, and have only two non-null fields. You're breaking the Student invariants, and that will cause a lot of confusion, and thus bugs.

Comment: I understand,but i only need those 2 Fields.Should i change something or do i have to tweak the names or return types.Would like to make it more acceptable approach.Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for a way to avoid casting each row from the resultList and having to manually create Student object then try using "[JPQL Constructor Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor)"

You're select query can be modified as:

```
"select NEW com.FullyQualifiedName.Student(student.id,student.enrollmentId) from Student as student"
```

and accept the query result directly as

```
 List<Student> studentList=multipleSelect.getResultList();
```

**or Simply:**

```
public List<Student> getStudentList(){
    return em.createQuery("select NEW com.FullyQualifiedName.Student(student.id,student.enrollmentId) from Student as student").getResultList();
}
```

**Note:**

1. Make sure Student constructor is called using fully qualified name.
2. Do not use JPQL with createNativeQuery.

Comment: Any other approach without using constructor?

Comment: I don't think there is any other approach. Java needs constructor invocation for objects no matter which approach you choose. What is the problem with this approach? All you need to do with this approach is say `return em.createQuery("select NEW com.FullyQualifiedName.Student(student.id,student.enrollmentId) from Student as student");`

Comment: you forgot to add #getResultList()

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha Ah, good catch :) Typical copy-paste error. Thanks!

Comment: @BandiKishore,nothing wrong,just wanted to avoid constructors at every possible point of invocation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output of the query to be of Student type then you'll have to create the query in a different way, i.e.,

```
TypedQuery<Student> multipleSelect=em.createQuery("select NEW your_package.Student(student.id,student.enrollmentId) from Student as student"
                                                 , Student.class);

List<Student> students = multipleSelect.getResultList();
```

However, this is not a good way to do this as the return type of the method would suggest that it is returning a completely filled `Student` object. Also, you'll have to make constructors for every combination. I would rather suggest you fetch a map, i.e.,

```
TypedQuery<Map> multipleSelect=em.createQuery("select NEW map(student.id as id,student.enrollmentId as eid) from Student as student"
                                              , Map.class);
List<Map> students = multipleSelect.getResultList();
```

This will return you a map with key as `"id"` and value as the actual id of the student.

Comment: Can you please have it represented according to my scenario,as described.

Comment: Just wanted to know is [TypedQuery<Map>] Map a class or an interface?

Comment: TypedQuery extends Query interface and it is used when a more specific resultset in expected.

Comment: TypedQuery<X>,i meant the X.

Comment: X is the Type whose class you would pass in the EntityManager#createQuery method, check the answer